# How to loop output to csv in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a function that returns a table of data. I created a query that runs the function and spools the output to a file. I need to know if there is a way to loop this and automate this output for many files.

```sql
set heading off
spool testfile.csv
select * from table(function(location));
spool off;
```

This code successfully leaves me with a csv file of the table. What I would like to do is loop it and feed it a list of locations and have it print me a file for each. When I tried to implement a loop I ran into an issue where my spool path gives me an error if there is a begin statement in front of it. This is concerning because if I wanted to use a function or procedure I would need to use a begin and end.

Comment: `spool` is a `SQL*Plus` command so it's not going to be available in a PL/SQL block running on the database.  If you want to create a file on the database server, you could use the `utl_file` package in a PL/SQL block rather than `spool` on the client.  If you want to create a file on the client machine, PL/SQL isn't going to be an option.